# how to reopen a docker container window again

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was able to run a docker container but if I do `sudo docker-compose up -d` but how to reopen/watch the screen again if I need and close again. I am using ubuntu.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to follow the logs of all of the containers that are included in the `docker-compose.yml` file, run the command `docker-compose logs -f` (probably with `sudo` in your case) in the same directory in which you already ran `sudo docker-compose up -d`. You can find more information on the command [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `docker attach` ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)). Usage is:

```bash
docker attach [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
```